# Can I add the limit the result of object return in Ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For Example, I want to know the User have many posts. So, I can get back post using this :

```
@user.posts
```

but I don't want to get all the posts back. I would like to limite the result, for example, top ten created, or may be sorted by some column. How can I do so? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always make a generic scope to handle the limit, such as putting this in an initializer:

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  named_scope :limit, lambda { |*limit| {
    :limit => limit[0] || 10,
    :offset => limit[1]
  }}
end
```

This makes limiting queries easy:

```
# Default is limited to 10
@user.posts.limit

# Pass in a specific limit
@user.posts.limit(25)

# Pass in a specific limit and offset
@user.posts.limit(25, 25)
```

For something more robust, you might want to investigate [will_paginate](http://github.com/mislav/will_paginate).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@user.posts(:limit => 10, :order => "created_at DESC")
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the [options](http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#M001316) available for the `has_many` association.

You could try something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_many :top_ten_posts, { :class_name => "Post", :order => :some_rating_column, :limit => 10 }
end
```

Comment: But sometime, I want all, some time I would like to want first 10, sometime is first 20. Can I pass a "filter" in get the result I want??

Comment: @Tattat: You could use multiple associations similar to the concept of named scopes.